# Xaml Radio button

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

How can I programmatically create X number of radio buttons that belongs to the same group in xaml...

The radio buttons will be based on the response from the server and they must all hv the same groupname

Answer (score 2):

Yes, In xaml you can set 'GroupName' property for RadioButton like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Your group name" Content="Your content"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Your group name" Content="Your content"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Your group name" Content="Your content"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Your group name" Content="Your content" IsChecked="True"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And if you want to create them by response, you can do this by **C#** code instead of xaml:

```
for (int i = 0; i < optionNumberOfResponse; i++)
{
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton()
    {
        Content = "Your content here",
        GroupName = "Your group name here",
    };
    YourContainer.Children.Add(rb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris... I am expecting a response from the server, the number of the options stated in the response will determine the number of radio button on my view

Comment: That's OK. I will update my answer, please read it once more.